# When would I use java Collections singletonMap method?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I don't understand why you would need java Collections [singletonMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap%28K,%20V%29)?
Is it useful in multithreaded applications?

Comment: @skaffman: That would be my bad. At first I thought the OP was referring to the Commons class `SingletonMap` so I edited it. I've since rolled back my changes ;)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Basically, it allows you to do this:

```
callAPIThatTakesAMap(Collections.singletonMap(key, value));
```

rather than this:

```
Map<KeyType, ValueType> m = new HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>();
m.put(key, value);
callAPIThatTakesAMap(m);
```

which is much nicer when you only have a single key/value pair. This situation probably does not arise very often, but `singleton()` and  `singletonList()` can quite frequently be useful.

Comment: I use singletonMap all the time in DAO's that use Spring's Named Parameter JDBC Template.  If you have a simple select statement like "select foo from bar where id = :barId" then you would need a parameter map with a single key-value pair, barId=123.  That's a great place to use singletonMap().

Comment: If any API takes map as input and i am using Collections.singleton(key,value) ,then i am passing immutable map, which might not be good for that API, because may be that API adds more elements to this map, and in this case, nothing can be done as it is immutable.

Comment: @AKS: in theory yes, but in practice read only access is far more common, and it should be clear from the API documentation whether entries are added to a map passed as parameter.

Comment: @PlabonDutta: No. Which you could have known by trying it, by looking at the API docs, or simply by thinking about what "singleton" means.

Answer (score 15):

It is useful if you need to pass a map to some general code (as a parameter, or as a result from a method) and you know that in this particular case -- but perhaps not in other cases that pass map to the same general code -- the map you want to pass has only a single key. In that case, the SingletonMap is more efficient than a full-blown map implementation, and also more convenient for the programmer because everything you need to say can be said in the constructor.

Answer (score 9):

Also, a SingletonMap implementation returned by Collections.singletonMap() has a smaller memory footprint than a regular HashMap. It only has to contain two member fields: the key and the value, whereas a HashMap maintains an internal array of Node objects plus other member fields. So if you are creating a *lot* of these maps in memory, it would be a prudent choice to use Collections.singletonMap().

Answer (score 6):

many answers told you when, but I want to point out when to `not use it`

**don't use it** if you want to `put items later on`,

because put implementation of `singletonMap` will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 5):

It's mainly for convenience and abstraction. Some APIs take a `Collection` as an argument and it's nice to have a simple way to convert objects to a `Set` or `Map`.

`singletonMap()` and `singletonList()` were actually introduced after `singletonSet()` in Java 1.3 because `singletonSet()` proved to be useful.

Comment: There is no singletonSet() method, it's just called singleton()

Answer (score 0):

This is just another example, but I wrote this line of code:

```
@Override public Map<Action, Promise<Boolean>> actOnResults() throws Exception {
    return Collections.singletonMap(Action.UPDATE_DATABASE, saver.save(results));
}
```

note the `@Override`. The interface more generally can take maps of many things; this particular instantiation just always returns a map containing one thing. Also note that the key to the map is an Enum. So the maps are never supposed to be big, they're just supposed to contain the results of whichever actions are specified. In my real example there are up to 5 actions, and this instantiation only uses one of them.

To be complete, `EnumSet` or `EnumMap` is often appropriate in these cases, but those are still annoyingly verbose compared to the code above.